# Getting debug logs for Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How to get the logs of debugging VB code in Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0?

Comment: What do you mean by "Logs of debugging?"

Comment: Do you want to attach a debugger to code that was written in VB 6?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to ask, intercepting debug.print statements on a built app try this: (i have used this tool but can't recall if Debug compile is necessary or if it works on a Release build)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output on your local system, or any computer on the network that you can reach via TCP/IP. It is capable of displaying both kernel-mode and Win32 debug output, so you don't need a debugger to catch the debug output your applications or device drivers generate, nor do you need to modify your applications or drivers to use non-standard debug output APIs.

DebugView Capture
Under Windows 2000, XP, Server 2003 and Vista DebugView will capture:

Win32 OutputDebugString
Kernel-mode DbgPrint
All kernel-mode variants of DbgPrint implemented in Windows XP and Server 2003
DebugView also extracts kernel-mode debug output generated before a crash from Window's 2000/XP crash dump files if DebugView was capturing at the time of the crash.